# Django 1.7 + Bower Unknown Command

Tags: python, django

I´m trying to install bower on a django project I have.

I executed both:

```
npm install -g bower
```

and

```
pip install django-bower
```

if I write`bower --version`
I get:`1.4`

however on my django project when writing

```
py manage.py bower install
```

or

```
 py manage.py bower_install
```

I get `Unknown Command: 'bower'`

This is my setting.py

```
    """
Django settings for agenda project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."),
)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@7j23xm3jv=(#gicejabv2ppa$063st+d@)2x^thld0(#!chwq'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'modulo_agenda',
    'schedule',
  'djangobower',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'agenda.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'agenda.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "site_media")
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.core.context_processors.request",

)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
)
BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "components")
BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap'
)
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 1 # Monday
```

Can anyone tell me what I´m doing wrong?

bower is installed on my computer but somehow I cannot get the manage.py script to recrognize it as a valid command. Maybe I forgot something on the manage.py?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

As referenced here:  https://github.com/nvbn/django-bower/issues/34

```
./manage.py bower_install
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks. I specified that I tried that command too on the question. Unfortunately it does not work for me.